# RSelenium <button class= expandPF Fz(s)....................." cannot find the css or the path of the buttun

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, yahoo-finance, rselenium

I am scraping yahoo finance and on financial tables there are "quarterly" and "expand all" clicks. When I inspect on buttons gives me <button class= expandPF Fz(s)....................." and I don't how to do it in CSS. the [link](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ADESE.IS/financials?p=ADESE.IS) and my code is;

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "class", ".expandPf")
```

But it gives error. I also tried using = "CSS" but same error.
[image: web site inspect]
Please Help!! :)) Thanks in advance

---

I also tried;

```
> webElem <-remDr$findElement("xpath", "//*[@id='Col1-1-Financials-Proxy']/section/div[2]/button/div/span")$clickElement()

Selenium message:No active session with ID b3685d1143434ead399da8235261106f

Error:   Summary: NoSuchDriver
     Detail: A session is either terminated or not started
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

but get this error.
If anyone has an idea please help :))

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `xpath` to click **Expand** and **Collapse**

```
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ADESE.IS/financials?p=ADESE.IS'
library(RSelenium)
driver = rsDriver(port = 4492L, browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)
remDr$findElement('xpath', '//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]/section/div[2]/button')$clickElement()
```

[image]

[image: after]

Comment: Hello, I've tried your suggestion but it gives the error below ```Selenium message:no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="Col1-1-Financials-Proxy"]/section/div[2]/button"}
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.61)```

Comment: Strange it worked for me.